# Function that increases at decreasing level

Tags: functions

I need to find a function that starts at 10 and ends at 280. The values between should increase at a decreasing level. It has been quite a while since I was in school, so I can't think of a suitable function.
The goal with the function in the end is to generate 100 numbers where the first is 10 and the last is 280.

Comment: Such as $\sqrt x$ for $[100,280^2]$?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of such functions. One such would be $$f(x) = 10\log(x) + 270$$

but there are infinitely many other functions that fit your description.

Comment: You typed almost verbatim what I was typing :)